# Best practices with creating and closing WCF clients for async methods

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous

I'm familiar with best practices with creating a WCF client, calling a standard method, then closing or aborting the client when complete but I'm wondering about async methods with clients.

I've got a manager class that has some pass through events for the consuming class to attach to in order to retrieve the results of an async call. For instance:

```
internal sealed class CommController
{
    public event GetClientIdEventHandler ClientIdReceived;

    private readonly LocalCommSvcClient _localCommSvcClient = new LocalCommSvcClient();

    public CommController()
    {
        _localCommSvcClient.GetClientIdCompleted += (o, e) => ClientIdReceived(o, e);
    }

    public void GetClientIdAsync()
    {
        _localCommSvcClient.GetClientIdAsync();             
    }
}
```

But I don't see where the client is getting closed and/or disposed of. I couldn't really find much best practices for closing WCF clients as it pertains to async usages. Where should I put my .Close() and/or .Abort() calls?

Comment: I thought it went through a standard REST request/response cycle (likely over HTTP), that with it being stateless, there is no need to "close" the client because nothing was really opened in the first place.  Though I could be dead wrong on this, I haven't had the pleasure of diving into the real nuts and bolts of WCF.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Open() a client before you are able to send a message like you do with synchronous clients. 
After communication is no longer needed (at least when you have received the response), you should Close() it to free resources.
Details depend on binding and behavior configuration of your service.
See e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx